# "There is no something" vs "no something"

Tags: phrases, ellipsis

Is it correct in English to write:

> No water
> No apple
> No dog

when there is no water/apple/dog?

Is there any rule when only one form is valid:

> There is no water

vs

> No water

Let's say I create a table and in one cell I want to write that there is no water in the pump:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | red |
| 12 | blue |
| 13 | no water in the pump |

In such context - is it correct just to say "no water in the pump"? Or do I have change it to "There is no water in the pump"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a narrative, you should normally use complete sentences. "There is no water in the pump." If you are putting labels on something or making entries in a table, it is not necessary to use full sentences, and "no water" or "no water in pump" is fine.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear for me now.